# Fixed vs variable length STRING field definitions in ECL

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I have a question regarding STRING field definitions.

Am I better off to fully qualify my STRING fields or allow them to be variable length?

For example I am working with a data file which contains multiple string data elements which can be up to 1000 characters in length.

When I define the ECL fields as STRING1000 the strings are padded and difficult to view in ECL Watch.

If I define the ECL fields simply as STRING, the string fields are adjusted to the length of the field value and much easier to read in ECL Watch.

With regards to my question, does either option affect the size of my dataset in memory or on disk?

What is the best practice I should follow?

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer to this question is:

IF you know the string is always going to contain n number of characters (like a US state code or zipcode field) OR the string will always contain 1 to n characters where n is a small number and the average length of the actual data approaches the max (like most street address fields) THEN you should define that field as a STRINGn. ELSE IF n is a large number and the average length of the data is small compared to the maximum THEN variable-length STRING would be best.

Both options affect the storage and memory size:

Fixed-length fields are always stored at their defined length.
Variable-length STRING fields are stored with a leading 4-byte integer indicating the actual number of characters following that instance (like a Pascal string)
Therefore, if you define a string field that always contains 2 characters as a STRING2 it occupies two bytes of storage, but define it as a STRING and it will occupy six.

Answer (score 0):

In ECL, if you are unsure of the max length of a field, you can simply define that field in your record structure as "string" and the compiler will adjust and choose for you. This is only recommended when absolutely necessary as your code can suffer performance issues and the file resulting from such operation may be slightly larger. However, usually the difference is hardly noticed in my experience.